# Are all JPEG files JFIF?

Tags: c#, wpf, jpeg

Active Directory can store images in JPEG File Interchange Format (JFIF) according to the [jpegPhoto Attribute definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676813(VS.85).aspx).  I'd like to use this but I'd never heard of JFIF.

First, are all JPEG files JFIFs?

Second, does a WPF JpegBitmapEncoder produce a JFIF file?  I guess if the first is true, this will be but if it's not...?

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#Compatibility says that EXIF is comparable but theoretically incompatible with the older JFIF, because each requires in its specs that its own « particular application segment (APP0 for JFIF, APP1 for Exif) must immediately follow the SOI marker ». Then it adds that « In practice, many programs and digital cameras produce files with both application segments included », so in practice « This will not affect the image decoding for most decoders, but poorly designed JFIF or Exif parsers may not recognize the file properly »

Comment: This is probably why IrfanView, in its "JPG lossless transformation", recommends to NOT select the "Write JFIF marker" option if you want to upload JPGs back to your digital camera. Versailles, Thu 11 Feb 2016 19:09:00 +0100

Answer (score 38, accepted):

JPEG = the compression algorithm (Joint Photographic Experts Group)

JFIF = the file format (JPEG File Interchange Format)

Effectively when you mention jpeg/jpg you are actually talking about JPEG/JFIF, although there is a spec for JPEG/TIFF and JPEG/EXIF (usually digital photos is where you'll see these)

A lot of the time whatever produces the EXIF file will also include what JFIF parsers need to decode properly, so it is transparent to the end user, but not entirely a "valid" and "to spec" EXIF file.

For internet use and transmission the default is JFIF, but not all jpegs are necessarily JFIF when you look under the covers.

Comment: I would just add that another perspective, that JIFF is a *media* use to store (and also transport) images encoded with JPEG compression.

Answer (score 8):

The JPEG File Interchange Format (JFIF) is an image file format standard. It is a format for exchanging JPEG encoded files compliant with the JPEG Interchange Format (JIF) standard. It solves some of JIF's limitations in regard to simple JPEG encoded file interchange. So all JPEGs are JFIF.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format). Apparently, JFIF is a more detailed subversion of the JPG format.

More details [here](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/)...

Also, it seems that JpegBitmapEncoder supports different codecs. Thus it could be that you use a Codec that does (or does not) create JFIF files. You would have to check the codec for this.