# Why is the quality of JPEG images produced by PIL so poor?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The JPEG images created with PIL (1.1.7) have very poor quality. Here is an example:

Input: https://s23.postimg.cc/8bks3x5p7/cover_1.jpg

Output: https://s23.postimg.cc/68ey9zva3/cover_2.jpg

The output image was created with the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('/path/to/cover_1.jpg')
im.save('/path/to/cover_2.jpg', format='JPEG', quality=100)
```

The red text looks really awful. Saving the image with GIMP or Photoshop does not even come close to the bad quality created by PIL.
Does somebody know why this happens and how it can be solved?

Comment: You're saving a JPEG of a JPEG. You're losing information twice. Are you sure that GIMP and Photoshop are actually processing the JPEG again and not just saving it as is (because the programs recognize it as a JPEG and, therefore, do nothing to it)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am aware of the fact that I'm losing information twice. It is just a very simple example. In production I am resizing the image as well :). Also if I resize the image in GIMP or Photoshop the resulting image looks much sharper. The two persons look almost the same in the two pictures but the red text looks really different.

Comment: I'm not doubting that it looks sharper from GIMP / Photoshop.  But is it any *different* from the input image?  After you save it as JPEG from GIMP / Photoshop, is anything changed?  If the answer is no, then PIL just might look "bad" because it's actually applying the JPEG compression, while the other isn't.  See what I'm getting at?

Comment: Your edit to my answer looked really familiar so I did a search - this isn't the first time I've answered this question, and there's a comment with the same information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481062/pil-jpeg-how-to-preserve-the-pixel-color

Comment: @MarkRansom That's where I got the solution from :)

Comment: @John _"You're saving a JPEG of a JPEG. You're losing information twice."_ - Re-encoding a JPEG as JPEG, assuming no processing in between and using the same encoder settings, does _not_ lose information twice. The JPEG process is deterministic, and applying it twice gives the same result as applying it once. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBX8GFqt6GA) has a decent explanation (crucial statement at about the 5:00 mark).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are two parts to JPEG quality. The first is the `quality` setting which you have already set to the highest possible value.

JPEG also uses [chroma subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling), assuming that color hue changes are less important than lightness changes and some information can be safely thrown away. Unfortunately in demanding applications this isn't always true, and you can most easily notice this on red edges. PIL didn't originally expose a documented setting to control this aspect.

Pascal Beyeler discovered the option which disables chroma subsampling. You can set [`subsampling=0`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg) when saving an image and the image looks way sharper!

```
im.save('/path/to/cover-2.jpg', format='JPEG', subsampling=0, quality=100)
```

The Pillow project took over where PIL left off and made many improvements, including documenting the formerly undocumented `subsampling` option.  It's been enhanced to take either an integer or string argument, but I still recommend `0` as shown above.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg

Note also that the documentation claims `quality=95` is the best quality setting and that anything over 95 should be avoided.  This may be a change from earlier versions of PIL.

Comment: thanks for this answer. given that it's now nearly 10 years old, is using `subsampling=0` still recommended when resizing images with pillow?

Comment: @Crashalot the [current docs for Pillow 9.4.0](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/JpegPresets.html) still state that `0` corresponds to `'4:4:4'` which means [no subsampling at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:4:4).  That's critical for images that will be viewed closely, and I wouldn't use anything else for my own JPEGs.

Comment: Any chance that we get this answer cleaned up? It's a thread on its own.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you're not wrong.  10 years ago when I wrote this answer the state of PIL was a mess, but I'm sure things have calmed down now.  It will take me some time to get it taken care of.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think I've cleaned it up a bit, let me know what you think.  I'll be deleting my comments too.