# Converting Image to Bytearray with Python

Tags: python, image, pdf

I want to convert Image file to Bytearray. I extracted image from pdf file with minecart lib, but I cant find a way to convert it to bytearray. This is my code:

```
import minecart
from PIL import Image
import io

pdffile = open('sample6.pdf', 'rb')
doc = minecart.Document(pdffile)


for page in doc.iter_pages():
    print(page)
    img = page.images[0].as_pil()

    print(img) # <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1641x2320 at 0x7FBDF02E6A00>

    print(type(img)) # <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
```

I have tried to use `bytearray(img)` but It does not work.
Do you have solution for this (solution that does not consume to much time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `io.BytesIO` buffer and write to it using `PIL.Image.save`. Set appropriate quality and other parameters as per requirement.

```
import io
from PIL import Image

def convert_pil_image_to_byte_array(img):
    img_byte_array = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_byte_array, format='JPEG', subsampling=0, quality=100)
    img_byte_array = img_byte_array.getvalue()
    return img_byte_array
```

**References:**

[Why is the quality of JPEG images produced by PIL so poor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303621/why-is-the-quality-of-jpeg-images-produced-by-pil-so-poor)