# Replaced the value of pixel from an image to a different value, but after getting the color value, it is different

Tags: python, python-2.7, jpeg, python-imaging-library

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("E:\\aaa.jpeg")
>>> color = im.getpixel((100,100))
>>> print  color
   (235, 229, 205)
>>> im.putpixel((100,100),(1,1,1))
>>> im.save("E:\\new.jpeg")
>>> im=Image.open("E:\\new.jpeg")
>>> color=im.getpixel((100,100))
>>> print color
   (8, 1, 0)
```

The value should have been (1,1,1)....but it shows(8,1,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEG is a *lossy* format.

On save, your pixel data is compressed with an algorithm that does *not* preserve precise pixel information. When reading and decompressing that data, there is no guarantee that specific pixels will still have the exact same colour value. `(8, 1, 0)` is close enough, as far as the JPEG compression is concerned.

Use a different format that preserves pixel data exactly like PNG, if this is important to your application.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I have been stuck for quite a while.

Comment: Also, is there an alternative, other than changing the format?

Comment: @user2524452, you can change the compression factor which might help a little but the values will never be exact - it's the nature of the format. That's why it's able to make the images so much smaller.

Comment: You can try to increase the quality setting, but you'll never get JPEG to preserve everything exactly as you set it. `im.save("E:\\new.jpeg", quality=95)` is the recommended maximum, `quality=100` disables the quantisation stage, resulting in ridiculous file sizes.

Comment: Also, see [Is Jpeg lossless when quality is set to 100?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7982409)

Comment: Thank you so much Mark and Martjin. Great help. :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, had a typo.