# ImageMagick convert adds several extra "border" colors from tiff to jpeg?

Tags: imagemagick

I created an 8-bit .tiff image ("test.tiff") containing a grid of 30 different color patches in the RGB color space using ImageMagick -convert.

When I convert this image into a jpeg (which is what I need) using:

```
convert -quality 100 -colorspace RGB -depth 8 test.tiff test.jpg
```

The identify -verbose command reveals that the resulting jpeg has several additional colors in the color table, each only taking up a few (1-4) pixels and residing very near the desired colors in RGB space. My assumption is that some kind of border bleeding is happening; maybe due to compression?

I don't understand why this border bleeding has occurred, especially given that it does not occur when I convert the tiff image to either a bmp or pcx image.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, JPEG is a [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression). The effects your experiencing are expected with the JPEG format. Setting the `-quality` of 100 will not have a 1-to-1 image result as tiff.

See additional answers:

- [Should I use JPG or TIFF for high-quality prints?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/10896)

> [...] because every time [JPEG] would save it it would generate some changes.

- [Is Jpeg lossless when quality is set to 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982451/438117)

> At [quality] 100, you just get the LEAST loss possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you created your 30 colour swatch, or how your histogram looks, but you might try adding `-dither None` and `-colors 30`  options to your `convert` commands:

```
convert test.tiff -dither None -colors 30 ...
```

Comment: Same result as before. Must be due to compression, as pointed out by @emcconville