# openCV set color is not displaying Red

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Why when i set a specific color of a pixel does it not show solid red? And it also appears to affect the surrounding pixels and not just the specific pixel I chose.

[image]

code

```
import cv2
import numpy
import os
print cv2.__version__

width = 60
height = 40

# create simple RGB images
img = numpy.zeros((height,width,3), numpy.uint8)
img[30,20] = [0,0,255]

cv2.imwrite('RGB.jpg', img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100])
os.startfile('RGB.jpg')
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you save an e.g. PNG?

Comment: PNG works just fine. I wonder why JPEG does this

Comment: For me even .jpg works with your code.

Comment: @RickM. it works for me but the pixel is not a solid Red color and it appears to adjust the surrounding pixels colors as well.

Comment: Relevant - [`Is JPEG lossless when quality is set to 100?
`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982409/is-jpeg-lossless-when-quality-is-set-to-100).

Comment: @JokerMartini It works for me as it should. I have one red pixel at the center. What version of OpenCV/Python/numpy are you using?

Comment: both are the latest ones.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.2.0 and with your code it works like a charm. "both are the latest ones" is dubious.