# Lossless JPEG is a special case of JPEG image compression

Tags: multimedia

I've read lossless jpeg is invoked when the user selects a 100% quality factor in an image tool.

What is the image tool they meant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post your source.

Comment: Fundamentals of multimedia book

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JPEG lossless when quality is set to 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982409/is-jpeg-lossless-when-quality-is-set-to-100)

Answer (score 0):

OK Image Compression is sorta like a ZIP file; JPG Takes up less space but has less quality then a PNG or TIFF. In short it removes Bytes and Changes The Algorithm, the Higher the Quality The More Space it Takes for the Algorithm Compression, Read More Here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression