# Converting a spectrogram image back to audio

Tags: audio, generative-adversarial-network, spectrogram

I have generated some Mel-spectrograms using librosa to use it for generative adversarial networks(GANs). I have saved the generated spectrograms through GAN in image format(.png). Now I am trying to convert the images back to audio. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I convert spectrograms generated with librosa back to audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132574/can-i-convert-spectrograms-generated-with-librosa-back-to-audio)

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Can you share the code snippet to implement this for spectrogram images

Comment: `S` in that code is your spectrogram image.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I have saved some spectrogram images in png format. I want to convert it to audio. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is, though it's not a good approach. Read the post and comments.

Comment: Thank you @LukaszTracewski. Can you suggest me a documentation where can I get the idea?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. What documentation?

Comment: [amar nabil taabane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16613331) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68692808) saying "i find this for spectrogram .. [https://github.com/sikora507/elgen/blob/master/src/audio%20analysis.ipynb](https://github.com/sikora507/elgen/blob/master/src/audio%20analysis.ipynb)"

Answer (score 0):

WaveNet can convert spectrograms back to speaking audio, a PyTorch version is available [here](https://github.com/as-ideas/ForwardTacotron/blob/master/models/fatchord_version.py)