# Convert Pillow Image to and from bytes: how to make the bytearray keep the same independent of image format?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I intend to convert bytes to Pillow image and then convert the image back to bytes. The goal is to keep the output bytes the same as the input bytes independent of the format of images. Here is a snippet I wrote.

```
from PIL import Image
import io

# Open the image file and read it into bytes
with open('beauty.jpeg', 'rb') as image_file:
    image_bytes = image_file.read()

# Convert the bytes to a Pillow image
pillow_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))

# Convert the Pillow image back to bytes
image_bytes_reconverted = io.BytesIO()
print(pillow_image.format)
pillow_image.save(image_bytes_reconverted, format=pillow_image.format)

# Ensure the original and reconverted bytes are the same
image_bytes_reconverted = image_bytes_reconverted.getvalue()
are_bytes_equal = image_bytes == image_bytes_reconverted

if are_bytes_equal:
    print("The first and second sets of bytes are equal.")
else:
    print("The first and second sets of bytes are not equal.")
```

I try my code on an [image](https://data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBYWFRgVFhYYGBgaGBwaGBoaGhwcGBgaGhwZGhgYGhocIS4lHB4rHxgYJjgmKy8xNTU1GiQ7QDs0Py40NTEBDAwMEA8QHxISHjQsJCs0NDQ0NDQ9NDQ0NDE0MTQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NjQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NP/AABEIAJwBQwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwUCBAYHAQj/xAA8EAACAQIEAwYDBQYGAwAAAAABAgADEQQFEiExQVEGImFxgZETobEHMkLB0RRicpLh8CNTgqKywhUzUv/EABkBAQADAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBf/EACERAQEBAQACAwADAQEAAAAAAAABAhESIQMxUSIyQWEE/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD2aIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgaeYYb4lNlFrkWFxdfUcxPHO1HYaqEDqoAVrOBe/Ei97WsbjYc7z2+R1VBBvwtvJ6PzPW7POoDabAm6nVcHYEG9vuyvq5Sb34z1bP0+I5YCwvsOgHATncRhRMdb46M/H1wTZa0jfCkcR/fnOzfBjpNLE4IEcJTPy+1tfDOenIOttpgi38Jb4vAnpNFqJB+7NZqVhrFjUE9b+xLIATVxzj7pNKltzsDUYehVb+LTyeqtp+k+wGA+DluGTe7UxUa/G9Qmof+YHpJ1fSMz2t673MhQ7zKqJionLbeuqfTYVZQdosuWqPEc/Pb9Pbyl6agAlbiaoP9+cavIZna8mzfL9LFH22OlrG1xfY9Ol+U7zsDR0YJFPHXUJ/naY5ng0qAhh5HmPWbnZij8PDhL30u9j4E6vzmfl2cXmeXq+UzGrjETdjaVec5qtBCx48p5RnfaCpXc7kLewUf048flJzm36TqyT29YxXbHDUz3n9hf6TDD9tcO5ADHc8eA899+k82ybsvWrWLHQvK+86ql9nq7EVbde6D9fGa+vrrPn7He08UrrqU3EgqNOTw+SYvDWNKprXmrHb0uNvQy2w2ZFiFdGR+h5nwPOU0vmfjecyJhM2afDMrF5WGmJJaI4ddZERPSeaREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQPk0M5q6aTfvd334/IGb8qM/ayKP3r+w/rIv0nP243G0ryofDXmeeZyUuqDvcL/AN+U496uIc3DNv0nLqddmbx0VTDesgfCXlJh8ViKbXa9ueq9jOoynHpW6huh/WZ2WNJeqipl3hKbH5UeU9BfDCV2KwcibsLmV5rmGAKqTblP0nUx1Ohh6epgLIoUX42UWnjWPwQsdp6PmWWftWBw7r9/4SHz7oDD3Hym+d9lYbxM6ivxnamoWsii3hvtOgwGZhkBcaW/Q2/KR5Fly0qKgqNR3Y23J6eUlxeFRlItt4cpTvFudR4mtxsZXVKs0qlKpTJF9Scuo8J9WpqmWr1rmcZO838ofuuvMd4eXA/9ZXESXAORUXxNj5HaUn2tfpq9r8ueqncF+o9b/pObyvIVpnW47w3APBZ6a9Lac1neEYglbg8rWPuDx9JrLfpX1fatp5y6uERC5Iv3eQHMy4wnaQA6XBRujC3t1nnuIwWJo6661jT2ue7ZSBxuN+P5ywXHYn4YOJoB0ZQwdAD3TazFTvbe+0v4W+4r5yXmnptLM1bmDDurchPLcJjrm9GptzRuXodx5TqspzJ22fj4cJW9n2tJL9OmFpkokVAXm2lKV51FqPTPsm0eE+x41Hk6GIieg4CIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiB8lB2lJGjpY++0v5WZ7Q1UW6r3h6cfleV19LZvNR5fmOX3cseG8zy9UUcpaY9LqT4Tz3OszdH0ksqX+8tibbngeB4cpyTutcd3ZnPa7bE4VHG4uPWQYLChG7oAHy9pR5bi3caqbmovMbah7W9pb4XFX3Ez32VpnlnV0BI6tK8woVrzc03ErEX053H4XjOw7H1y2DCXs1N2QeANnHT/6t6SmxdMdJd9k8Lai55O5I9ABf3v7TTF56Z/JPXVDnma4/DXfVTekqsx1KNgCLC62NySB5mWSZ06qjV6YVXAKvTYVKe/UjdfUTdz7CmpTahoZ/iDSbA6VFx3i3AWIBt4TYw+XFKKUmIIVAthtfax34y/qz2z9y+vpou4bcEEH5zD9l5iW+GypFUKF0gcLfpNl8OAJTxrTzjnKlK0kynD6ql+Si/qdh+Z9JsYwSxyXDaU1Hid/0+UrnPdcW1rmU1YWFpoNR1GWFYXmNNLTXntl305ftLlCuvwmBKuGViPw7alPutvWT5HTo4fC6XIVAAoDfeIUBRtxJuJY5tgTU4ErbmCQfS0r6ORL+K7eLG/1k51c9Lma5bXFZlli13vh6Olbk6z3WJub2A8STxnXZBkOhRqNz1MvcPglHKWFOnIvdfaezP8AVHQwwEmNOTBZ8czXxnGXleodMT7eJRdbxETqchERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERA+SDFkaHJ4aTfysbyecz2vzYIooqe8/H91f6nbyvK61MztWzm61JHPObicf2qoIiq54lXVdibMUcI1hfg5U9Z1KPteaeLwSPpLoHs17MoYW57GcXx3+XXdrP8eKjLsFhUw1FGU/taqLmn3WQncCo3AkA8Gv5SbC4Wpc69yeJ6+PnLVMAAe6oA2tYW4TdShaTu3VMSZnpqYaiZZATGwEhq4i0z5xbvUi0C7BBxJt5dTOwoUQiKq7BRaVGRYQqPiOO83AdF/Uy5BvNczk6x3e3jNdz6T4aIBmdISRprM9jK3lRaZrYh7CbFV7SmxteU3eRfGe1q1FLuFHM7+XOXx7qhZX5Zh9N3bieHgJPUqSMTxnV9e7xKTMwJqLUmwr7S3UWDLPgSfdU+iQl9RJsoshQyQPLxTTMyFmh6k16lSNaRnLLXE1dc+zLya+LpIiJ2uEiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgV+b5mmHpmo58FHNm5KJ52C1ao1Vt2Y3PQdAPADabXaus9XEbk6EJVR0sbMbdSQfS0qjmbIbBNh85x/NvyvP8ju+H4/HPf9qwqjlM0XaaC5iH5WP1m7RqXEzy01K2LzIvNZqk1quIk6pnKevWmxkWB+I+th3FO1/wATcfYSgr4njO9y3EIlOmo3UoDfrcXJ9STK55b2m+yektfETOjixwkeNpqRqU/0nP1cWVaNasquczUdphztFV5qZbX1IG6j8p8xNa038+ZYeH8kWKrStod9xfgN/wBJ8xmIlZSx2h9R4cD5dfpMLrtdMzyOxstuNprOingwlLiKrONSHUOoP16TnsTmtZW0ojN+8TpX02JPymnlfxWY/wCuzr09O8ho4ve057AZniGNqlMgdVOof6hYEfOSriCaiqON9/ASutWLTPp1CvJVaaVIydWkyqWNkNPjPINUxZ5Pkr4snqSBqkxd5ru8rdNM5Z/EiauqJTq/HdRET0nlkREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREDgO1uWVabtWRS6G7WH4WNyQegJ5+M4vA9p6nxlp18Pp1GwZTqG+wLC3DxnuN55JmuLVq9RqahQzbaQBwAUHbmQLnxJnL8uM59/rr+HetevxX9oaiIUZCO8Rw9JaYZ+4pPSVuHyhC2tyzkfd1HZfIDnLN+FhMJ6jpt6iq1ppV6slczXcStq8iG95Z4DNXRQhAZR92/FfI9PAzQVJIqR3hZK6PLswepqFtWldR4A28LbHl0mnmBH3r26/3yln2Pw9hUqHgQEHjzb8pe1Mvpv99FIvexFxeW8fKMrqZ1UHZwk4dGO1wSPIklT7WM+Y15aiwW0o8eZbU5mRTF7q1V4mpKnEvN7EmVtaYt2o1RlN1JU9QSD7ibWAzJzURHYurMFOrc7m1wePOarpNvIcLrxCDkG1HyXvfUCWzb1S/ruMNhxpG0z/ZlBuFAPW0npobT4xm1npl5e0OmLzImYFpVZ9vI3aC0idpFqZGLtIHaZuZA8ra0kR6okcSOp49EiInpvJIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiIHP9qax0pSuwWoWVips1gpIW/IE2v4C3OeXimEYDXrVgGRuTA/mOY4z1btNlBxNEoraHBurcLHgQbb2IJE8hzXLq1N2QnUVtqZTqUm21m4kjy8Jh8s66v/Pzi4pVOUyd5zODxlVGCuhIJtexH1EvRUvOXUs+3TOMnkWmZA3kiiUaMUSSaJkBPshHXcZWqLh6YXhpBP8AEdz87yVnK8ZyGBxrDTTVdZJsgBItfci3McT7zffEYkDei1r8A1/rz9TN+9npj4Xq8OJmlit5RJnhLqhRwzW20OePM2BFpdXuJnbU+PjVTiUmjUSW1dJqOko1VrU5u5HXFOrc7BlK36XsR8xb1hkka0CzBRxYgD1Nozfatnp0ozXRsSPIyVMyR+BF/OVuK7MpU0hmfui19RBPn4TXPYtB92o6nwdiRt4zp5VOZ+++14Kk+3lZgsnrIReqWUcda970II+ks1WU16PX+MWkbSYiYMJSpiFlkbJNi0xYQt1q/CibESOJ67SIiem8oiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgRVb2NuNjbz5TxzNMyOrQRYpswPEvc3sOPT2ns80MXlNCpcvSRieJ0jUf9Q3lNy6npr8XyeF+nia1Gc6ifIdBNxOEue0+Rrh6+lPusupRzXcgqeo6HjKgLOPcsvK7camp2JFMlDTXBn01Jk0bGqfGqTUetNarirSeDpOy+MVcSmogXVlUnhqI2/Mesuq+LfUVsSP3r289N55dXxV53PYHMWxK1KDnUyKGRju2gmxUnnY6f5ppm2zxjPXM/wAl3TdyNzbyAH0mXKbFXD6ZqtK67/pPaCqJrOJsuZruZlV0DSJamhlccQQfaZu01qjRB0lPFa7shJA3IHFQeo5TNcceC7f31lBklQiumk8bg+RB/QTpDh972E6Jq3PWd9XiRGPM3gmAs+GUo+GRkzJzIyYTH28xJjVMGeQk1T7IdcSR3URE9F5hERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQOB7foRVpueBQqPNSSf+QnI3nqnaLJxiaRS9mG6noeh8DPLMxyjE0CVZGtyIFwfIjjOX5sXvY7Pg3nnKidxNWriZEEqOdKozHoFJPsJZ4Tsdjatv8IoOrkL8jv8phMW/Ub63mfdUdbFTRqYgmeiYb7MKh/9ldF/hVm+pWbyfZbR/FXqHyVR9bzSfDr8Z358fryVmM7/AOyTDH4mIrclRUHiXbUfbQPeWGa/Zgq0ycPVdnAuFqBbN4BgBY+fy4zS+y/FaHxNB+65CsAdj3NSuLdRqXbzls4ub7U1ubnp2+OcXMqajyfGVuJlVWxMx3e1tjPIkqPNV6kgq4mQM5Mz40S1Kk1neZimTyn04cyODd7Ni9ceCsflb851ymchkzaKyMdgbqf9Qt9bTqar6SQZtj6Za/skea7tMXxE1qleKmRI7yJ6k1K2Kmm+LleLcWT1pDUxIlY+KvI2LHe23U7D3McS3mxY6xKb9pp/51L+df1iTxHY9liInovLIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAnyfYgYKoHAATOIgIiIHyeU/aHlrYfFJjKV01m+ocqi8f5l5c+9PVpzXb+iGwVQn8JQjwOsD6MZTc7F/jvNRxtHtFTqL/iA03tuVGpD4gcV8t5hVxtDjrZvBVP/a05mhw9JMZxV3z0uv8AzFJeFJm83A+gMjbPxyoqPNifyEpWmEqtxdntE3Kkn+79Zge0bc6SHyLA/UymMwMlHHSYXO6LkK6mmTwJOpL+J2K+otOkTHFV0VQSB91xuQPHqPGeXVPznY9l8Q1TCsHN/htpU89JHAnoOUtPX0rV0+JT/MS3iwB9jNWti6Y41E9CW/4gyrxSC81CglLtaRYVMenVm8l2/wBxE06mYqPupf8Aia/yAH1kLIJC0r51PGNfM6v4SqfwqPqbn5ynxlR33dmb+Ik/XhLKoJp1kEdtVqs0RJ7T7J6rx//Z) online but the result indicated they are not equal.
My questions are:

1. Why the input and the output are different?
2. Could you provide me a correct version please?

Comment: You are using JPEG and JPEG is ***lossy***. It loses stuff. It discards things that are less perceptible to the human eye in order to save space and better compress images. If you want to retain information down to the last bit, you need to use a lossless format, e.g. PNG. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058628/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74428535/2836621